# Understanding JavaScript for-loop better

Tags: javascript, for-loop

While reading code from a JS Editor ([Tern](http://ternjs.net/)), I have come across various uses for the for-loop as seen in the snippets below:

**code snippet 1** @ [lines 463-468](https://github.com/marijnh/tern/blob/master/lib/tern.js):

```
for (;;) {
  /* some code */
}
```

**code snippet 2** @ [lines 97-100](https://github.com/marijnh/tern/blob/master/lib/typescript.js)

```
for (var i = 0; ; ++i) {
  /* some code */
}
```

On the same note, I also have come across a for-loop with an empty body e.g:

```
for (var p; p; p = someValue) /* empty body */ ;
```

I am trying to understand what happens in **code execution flow**.

My take is that for code in snippet 1, the for loop has no conditions, so it may continue endlessly? For code in snippet 2, `i` is continually incremented without a limit? For the third one, the loop continues till `p` is assigned something that evaluates to `false`?

These are the ideas I have in my mind yet I am not sure. Please assist.

Comment: You are correct. The first two loops can finish if there is a `break` in their bodies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### In Short

First of all you are correct in all your assertions.

- The first loop runs until it is exited from abruptly (with a break, return, throw etc..).
- The second loop runs until it is exited from abruptly but also performs a variable assignment, and increments a value.
- The third for loop runs like a normal for loop until the center condition is falsey. Its body is empty.

---

### But Why does JavaScript do this?

Let's dig into *why* this happens.

If we take a closer look at [the language specification](http://es5.github.io/#x12.6.3) we can see that the following happens in a for loop:

> IterationStatement : for ( ExpressionNoIn(opt) ; Expression(opt) ; Expression(opt)) Statement

I will treat these statements and that definition for the rest of the answer.

Now let's go through the cases.

#### In case one of `for(;;)` the following happens:

- ExpressionNoIn is not present, so nothing is called for that clause (As clause 1 states).
- The second expression is not in, so we do not return calls (as clause 3 states).
- The third expression is empty so no "incremenetion" is performed (as clause 3.f states).

So it would basically repeat endlessly just as you predicted (until broken from with a `break` or returned from, or thrown from and generally anything that causes abrupt completion). (As clauses e and d tell us).

#### In the second case `for (var i = 0; ; ++i)` the following happens:

- ExpressionNoIn is present, so we evaluate it, and assign it with get value (as clause 1 states). We do not assign it.
- Then we repeat endlessly since the second expression is not here. So we continue until abrubt execution happens or a break happens. More specifically this is defined [here](http://es5.github.io/#x8.9).
- We increment `i` on every iteration as clause f states.

#### In the third case `for (var p; p; p = someValue) /* empty body */ ;` the following happens:

This evaluates as a for loop. Statement is empty indeed but the for loop does not really care. The only difference is that no value is *returned* from the for loop. Basically it's a full and legal for loop. `;` is simply an empty statement. It is useful when you want to run a for loop with no content in the actual loop. You see this sometimes in feature detection. This is also useful when you want to find the minimum `n` such that... .

You are correct in that it runs until the value is falsey, or more accurately [calling `ToBoolean` on it produces](http://es5.github.io/#x9.2) `false`. As clause 3.a.ii specifies.

As you can see, this is all in the spec and well defined :)

---

### Why do coders do this?

**In the first snippet** the perform their flow control with [a `break` clause](http://es5.github.io/#x12.8). `if (eol >= pos || eol < 0) break;` (they check for the end of line, and this could be done in a more conventional for loop).

In the second snippet again they do flow control using break:

```
 if (!definitions.hasOwnProperty(uniq)) { name = uniq; break; }
```

They again put it in a break statement inside the for loop.

**The third snippet** is out of context, but let's say we want to (trivial example) find the first number bigger than 10 (or the 10th div element, or occurance of a string - you get the idea). We could do :

for(var i=0;i<=10;i++);

And get the first number bigger than 10.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use `while (true)`?

Comment: @Nate For example when code golfing `for(;;)` is shorter :P Honestly there is no good reason to use `for(;;)` I explained _why_ it behaves this way and not why one would use it in code.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in your understanding.

The first snippet is an infinite loop; there is no termination condition, so the loop will (in itself) continue forever.  This is almost certainly accompanied by a `break` statement somewhere within the body, which will exit the loop when it is run.  (The other option is that a thrown exception exits the loop, although it is bad practice to use exceptions as control flow.)  This pattern (or an equivalent `while (true) {...}` ) usually occurs when the exit condition is too complex to express within the loop statement.

The second snippet is similar to the first, in that without a termination condition it will run forever.  This will also require a `break` statement (or exception) to terminate the loop.  The only difference here is that a counter variable is also being incremented on each iteration.

The third snippet is a loop with no body, though the test and variable update happen on each iteration of the loop.  As you expected, this continues until `p` evaluates to `false`.  This for loop is exactly equivalent to the while loop version:

```
var p;
while (p) {
    p = someValue;
}
```

which perhaps makes it clearer that the assignment happens repeatedly until `!p`.